# Laravel: Keep Displaying The View When Have Errors

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I am new to Laravel. I have a problem, so I have a guestbook table that have 0 records

`Table: guestbook
+-------------------------------------------+
|id|name|email|phone|created_at|updated_at|
+-------------------------------------------+`

I want to get the first data using eloquent

```
$guestbook = Guestbook::first();
return view('guestbook.index', compact('guestbook'));
```

when I try to access it on browser, it shows error `Trying to get property 'name' of non-object`. I read some articles to set the `APP_DEBUG` to `false`, after that it shows error `500 server Error`

The question is how can I see the view if there is no record on the guestbook table? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have the logic in your view account for the possibility of $guestbook being null.  Something like `@if ($guestbook) ... stuff that renders guestbook ... @endif`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`APP_DEBUG` `false` will hide your errors. but the error is still exists there.

As you said that in your `guestbook` table doesn't have any records.

While you fetching the first record by using `first()` method you're getting `empty` collection and it assign to `$guestbook` variable.

The best way to resolve is to use **[null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op).**

In your **blade file** do it as below.

```
$guestbook->name ?? '';
```

Comment: Big Thanks! it helped my case! what is`?? ''` mean in Laravel? thank you

Comment: ?? is turnery operator. if your value is not set there you will get  ' ' there. and the name is exists in your table the value will be your name. :)

Comment: Instead *turnery*, actual word is **ternary**. Being said that, this is not ternary operator but rather null coalescing operator. Shorthand ternary operator would be `?:`.